# Booting Kali Linux from live usb, USB skipped

Tags: kali-linux, live-usb

OK so I made a bootable USB with Kali on it and I've used it on two different laptops and it booted just fine, but when I try booting it on my laptop it just skips the USB and boots from the hard drive. The two laptops that it did boot on were running Windows (one had vista the other had 10) but on mine I have Ubuntu installed and before that I was running mint, I don't know if that's the problem but it's the only thing I can think of right now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to BIOS at the machine startup and change the boot order. USB needs to be before HDD. You can probably go to BIOS pressing `F12`, or some other `F`. Look for an instruction just after you power up. There may also be a special boot menu allowing you to set the order for just one startup.

Comment: I did that, the USB is first then the hard drive I also made sure my USB ports were active while the computer is asleep. Also I loaded ubuntu with a USB right after I tried kali and it worked with no problem

Comment: Do you have another USB with some live system that you know works fine, with which you could try the laptop?

Comment: Yeah I used a USB with Ubuntu 16 and it booted up just like it should, and I made both of the live USBs using "universal USB installer"... And the kali live boot works but it only works on Computers with windows installed

Comment: Also check if the Kali USB is still bootable. It might have got spoilt somehow somewhere.

Comment: Is the USB device detected in BIOS by going into the boot order section?

Comment: Yeah, it says sandisk extreme next to the usb option, I tried using other usb ports to but that didn't work, and I just got done running the kali live boot on my other laptop, it worked fine